# NAudio PlaybackState never stops?

Tags: c#, .net, audio, naudio

I'm using **NAudio** to create a simple audio player but I can't find a solution that could change the `PlaybackState` of my `WaveOut` stream to "Stopped" and consequently fire the `PlaybackState` event.

I did it as shown below:

```
private BlockAlignReductionStream stream = null;

private NAudio.Wave.WaveOut output = null;

private void Add_to_stream()
        {

            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Settings.Default.m + "\\","*"+selected_music+"*");

            if (files[0].EndsWith(".mp3"))
            {
                NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader mp3fr = new NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader(Settings.Default.m + "\\" + selected_music + ".mp3");
                var pcm = NAudio.Wave.WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(mp3fr);
                stream = new NAudio.Wave.BlockAlignReductionStream(pcm);

            }
            else if (files[0].EndsWith(".wav"))
            {
                NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader wavfr = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(Settings.Default.m + "\\" + selected_music + ".wav");
                var pcm = new NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32(wavfr);
                pcm.PadWithZeroes = false;
                stream = new NAudio.Wave.BlockAlignReductionStream(pcm);
            }
            else throw new InvalidOperationException("file type is not supported.");

            output = new NAudio.Wave.WaveOut();
            output.Init(stream);

        }
```

Originally, I was using  [DirectSoundOut](http://naudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/e43c857bbbe2#NAudio/Wave/WaveOutputs/DirectSoundOut.cs) instead of [WaveOut](http://naudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/e43c857bbbe2#NAudio/Wave/WaveOutputs/WaveOut.cs) class and I was being able to overcome this problem, but that one doesn't support Resuming.

I know that there are lot of people who has already faced this problem, but is there an alternative for both things (Resuming and firing PlaybackState)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add a WaveCallbackInfo into the constructor of your WaveOut class to get events raised.

```
output = new NAudio.Wave.WaveOut(WaveCallbackInfo.FunctionCallback());
output.PlaybackStopped += (pbss, pbse) => { Debug.WriteLine("Stopped"); };
```

Comment: I've done what you said but it's not working properly (actually, it only works if it's the first time that the stream receives a value): the event fires in the middle of the next song.

Comment: You have to remember that the Wave playing is handled on a different thread. It only calls raises the event if either Stop is called or the WaveOutEvent callback is set after the object Dispose/Close methods are called.

Comment: @rene I'm not sure what that means

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of `BlockAlignConversionStream` and `WaveFormatConversionStream`. `Mp3FileReader` emits PCM directly (assuming you are using a recent version of NAudio).

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you! The only problem I'm having right now is to pass another value to the output.Init(). I used a new EventHandler to throw a message when the PlaybackState event fires and Dispose() the output, but then, when I call a procedure to do the rest of the task i.e. to use the output.Init(), it simply ignores all the lines below and nothing happens (btw, without any error message).. I perceived it while debugging, it's like "the time wasn't enough for the event to call another thing and it simply breaks".